# How do I create a scheduled task to empty all domain users' Recycle Bin on the first of every month?

Tags: powershell, group-policy, scheduled-task

As the title suggests, I would like to empty users recycle bin on the first of every month. This is what I have so far. I would like more of a proof read to know if I am going about this the right way, or could accomplish this in a better way. Thank you all in advance.

I have created a GPO called "Empty Recycle Bin Monthly" - It is Linked and Enforced
[GPO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwBtW.png)

I have configured under User Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel > Scheduled Tasks, a task named EmptyRecycleBin and configured as follows: 
[Scheduled Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whSj1.png)

I have the trigger scheduled to start on today as a test, but should it work, will be the first of every month. 
[Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FqCe.png)

I have the Action set to Start a Program. This will be powershell, with arguments to empty recycle bin:

Program: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Add Arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command Clear-RecycleBin -Force -Confirm:$False
[Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rmhu.png)

I have no common options enabled.

[Common Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMJlD.png)

My main question here is regarding the option on Common Tab: "Run in as logged-on user's security context"

AND on the General tab under Security Options: 
"When running the task, use the following user account:"
I have this set to "%LogonDomain%\%LogonUser%"
The reason for this is to ensure that the task runs as the user who is logged in. Are my settings correct? Thank  you in advance!

Comment: One quick way to test this would be the log in as a user, go to the Task Scheduler, and manually run the task to see if it empties the Recycle Bin.

Comment: That is a good idea. Do a gpupdate /force to make sure they have received the task, then manually trigger. Thank you for the insight! 

I actually confirmed it was working under my account, but I am the domain admin, so curious if it will work with non-admins.

Comment: This is easy to test as well. I don't think that this task will require Admin Rights to run. What you can do is create a normal domain account (non-admin), log in as that user and try to run the task manually to see if it works. You can also try running that Powershell command as the user directly to see if it actually empties the Recycle Bin as expected.

Comment: An off-topic note: consider enabling the _Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled task is missed_ option (`Settings` tab).

Comment: The `-Confirm:$False` is not needed when using `-Force`. Also the security principal could be Everyone or BUILTIN\Users.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. As it is set, it worked flawlessly, nice to know I can test from the individual as well. I confirmed this today!

@JosefZ thank you for that! That is nice to know. I will make that change.

Comment: @GregAskew perfect. That is great to know as well.

Comment: Did everything here as suggested but the script did not empty the RecycleBin. When I run from the comand line it works.
I'm using BUILTin\Users I get a 0 message in the actions.
Server 2019
Windows 10

Comment: configured under User Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel > Scheduled Tasks, a task named EmptyRecycleBin and configured as follows: If I choose this option I cannot get the  Policy  work so I  use  Computer instead.